# How to code lowercase query oracle 11g in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g

In this case, I use Oracle 11g and Devexpress. I have a table named `Employee`, which has 3 fields (Id, Name, Address). When I show data in Navicat using Oracle Query it worked properly.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Address FROM Employee
```

but when i use that query in C#, the query doesn't work, this my code:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(@"SELECT Id, Name, Address FROM Employee", connection.con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds, "Employee");
gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I guess that my oracle query syntax in C# doesn't recognized lowercase syntax. Perhaps must be uppercase.Any suggestion on how to solve this lowercase syntax issue in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_ exactly? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: i got error like this `ORA-00904: \"Id\": invalid identifier`

Comment: Maybe it is a collation issue? Have you tried to write it as `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(@"SELECT ""Id"", ""Name"", ""Address"" FROM ""Employee"" ", connection.con);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ORA-00904](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm) error means that a column name is invalid or missing. Please correct your query.

Answer (score 0):

ID and NAME are oracle restricted words and shouldn't be used as column names as this can give some problems - maybe that's the case here. To explicitly call those column use "", for example:

```
SELECT "Id", "Name", Address FROM Employee
```